# Handling KeyboardInterrupt in scipy.integrate.odeint

Tags: python, exception, scipy, numerical-integration

Is there a reasonable way to handle exceptions in the evaluation of the derivative in calls to scipy.integrate.odeint?

This issue becomes important if the integrator is called in a tight loop, and you need to stop the execution for some reason. At the moment, I've resorted to converting `KeyboardInterrupt` to a `SystemExit` exception (see below) to make the process exit, which is fine, but obviously not ideal.

The scipy.integrate bindings and Fortran code seem to be doing some manipulation of odepack.error, but I'm not really sure if those exceptions are propagating out into Python.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy
import sys
import time

def derivative_faststop(func):
    def impl(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print sys.exc_info()
            sys.exit(1)
    return impl

@derivative_faststop
def f(x, t):
    # NB. the sleep is only present to model the real system
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return [1.0]

ts = numpy.linspace(0.00, 1.0, 11)
print odeint(f, [0.0], ts)
```

Comment: If it doesn't work as expected without workarounds, it's probably a bug. In that case, please file a bug report at http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/report